# HTML5 validation on existing values in an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that I am trying to validate using HTML 5 (and jQuery).
The form has initial values that are loaded in from a database. The users can edit the data and then submit the form. I have an input box with maxlength set to 6 but sometimes the value pulled from the DB has more than 6 characters in it. If the user doesn't do anything and just clicks submit then I want an HTML 5 validation warning. But the form just submits without a warning

```
<form id="checkValues" method="post">
<input id="reading01" name="reading01" type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="6" value="12345678" pattern="{0,6}">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

I have tried adding a pattern {0,6} but this doesn't make any difference. 
I don't want the form to remove characters automatically, the user must do this.
I tried using jQuery validate, but I don't think I am doing it correctly:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    const $reading01 = document.querySelector('#reading01');
    $reading01.validate();
}
```

Comment: Try validating it through Jquery by catching the value and then checking if its empty or not.

Comment: check the value by adding if condition in jquery   may it will help u out. var value = $(this).val();
    if ( value.length > 6

Answer (score 1):

If you normalise the `<button>` (ie. give it `type="button"` rather than `type="submit"`) you can take advantage of the **HTML5 Constraint API** for Form Validation.

The **HTML5 Constraint API** enables you to define your own validation constraints.

Once the form validates, you can use `submit()` to submit the form.

**Working Example:**

```js
const checkValuesForm = document.getElementById('checkValues');
checkValuesFormSubmitButton = checkValuesForm.querySelector('[data-type="submit"]');

const checkValues = (formSubmitted = false) => {

  const reading01 = document.getElementById('reading01');
  
  if (reading01.value.length > 6) {
    
    reading01.setCustomValidity('This number cannot be more than 6 digits long');
    reading01.reportValidity();
  }

  else {
  
    reading01.setCustomValidity('');
    
    if (formSubmitted === true) {
    
      checkValuesForm.submit();
    }
  }
}

checkValuesFormSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', () => checkValues(true), false);
reading01.addEventListener('keyup', checkValues, false);
window.addEventListener('load', checkValues, false);
```

```html
<form id="checkValues" method="post">
<input id="reading01" name="reading01" type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="6" value="12345678" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

---

## Further Reading

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation
- https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-html5-constraint-api-for-form-validation/

Answer (score 0):

you just need to display warning or prevent going further , in that case you can do your own validation by getting id and check it is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Like **Rounin says Je sus Monica** said, using `setCustomValidity` is the cleanest way to send a message to inform of an error on a input. Still, since you are using a `submit` button, you can listen to your form's `submit` event and validate it before send the request. Also, you can use the [`Document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) read only property, which returns a collection of `HTMLFormElement`. I like how it looks codewise, because it is very easy to understand that you are working with a form.

```js
const form = document.forms['checkValues'];
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const validatedInput = form.elements['reading01'];
  if (validatedInput.value.length > 6) {
    validatedInput.setCustomValidity("The input value cannot be longer than 6.");
    return;
  }
  form.submit();
});
```

```html
<form id="checkValues" method="post">
  <input id="reading01" name="reading01" type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="6" value="12345678" pattern="{0,6}">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

One more thing, and this is just a personal taste, when naming variables, I normally add the **$** symbol for `jQuery` elements. So if by chance I am using a `jQuery` library, I can identify which variable holds a plain `javascript` element and which a `jQuery` element.